# issue with displaying sprites in cocos2d

Tags: python, cocos2d-iphone

Here is my cocos code:

```
class Startbox(Layer):

def __init__(self):
    Layer.__init__(self)

    self.batch = BatchNode()

    self.add(self.batch)
    
    img = pyglet.image.load('images/map_sprites.png')
    
    tileset = pyglet.image.ImageGrid(img, 3, 15, 96, 96)

    x, y = 0, 0
    
    for i in range(10):
    
        for j in range(10):
            
            spr = Sprite(tileset[1])
            spr.x = x
            spr.y = y
            
            self.batch.add(spr)
            
            x += 96
        y += 96
        x = 0
```

I'm trying to get a sprite and display is side by side to cover the window.
That code produces a faulty result, the tiles have a space between them like this:

[image: notice the black lines]

I don't understand why this happens, or how to fix it. The following pyglet code does basically the same thing, but with the sprites properly lined up and not creating any black lines:

```
class screen(pyglet.window.Window):

def __init__(self, w, h):
    super(screen, self).__init__(w, h)
    
    sprite_sheet = grid(pyglet.image.load("images/map_sprites.png"), 3, 15)
    
    self.batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
    
    self.all_sprites = []

    x, y = 0, 0
    
    for i in range(10):

        for j in range(10):                
            
            sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(sprite_sheet[1], batch=self.batch)
            sprite.x = x
            sprite.y = y

            self.all_sprites.append(sprite)
            
            x += 96
        y += 96
        x = 0
```

---

**EDIT:** I found the solution, and wanted to post it as an answer for the sake of clarity in case someone stumbles upon this in the future, but I guess editing my OP will be sufficient.

From *Claudio Canepa* in the [Cocos2d Google groups](https://groups.google.com/group/cocos-discuss?hl=en) list:

> You can try passing do_not_scale=True in the director.init call , this will use ortographic projection which is better suited for tiles.
>
> You can look at examples for cocos tilemaps in the scripts
> test_tiles.py
> test_tmx.py
> test_platformer.py

The implementation is ultra simple:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    director.init(width, height, do_not_scale=True)
    director.run(Scene(Startbox()))
```

Comment: cast coordinates to integers

Comment: make sure the x/y coordinates of all tiles do not have a floating point component, ie 1.2345 -> 1.0  No idea how casting is done in python but at least there should be floor() function.

Comment: Great! Helping me solve the same case in my new isometric game.

Answer (score 1):

Not worked in python version of cocos2d, but observed same in iPhone version of cocos2d. So this may help :-

« If SpriteSheet created with Zwoptex then add sprite spacing gap to 2px +.

« Edit ccConfig.h file and define this

```
#ifndef CC_FIX_ARTIFACTS_BY_STRECHING_TEXEL
#define CC_FIX_ARTIFACTS_BY_STRECHING_TEXEL 1
#endif
```

Refer my answer in this: [Thread in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648443/ios-graphical-issue)