# Black line between Tiles on iPhone, but not in simulator

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, tile

I have a 15x17 Tilemap with 58x58 Tiles, made in Tiled. When I run it on the iPhone Retina 3.5-inch iOS7b5 Simulator, it works fine. When I run it on a iPhone 4 iOS7b5, I get a 1 pixel vertical black line between the  first and second tile. My tileset looks like this, 3 spacing, 3 margin and 58x58 Tiles. Tiled is told these are the settings.

[image: TileSet 58x58]

(I'm aware the colour are horrible, but i'm just testing)

Any quick fix to black lines? Force-reloading it once or twice just to punch it in the right place?

Comment: in ccConfig.h  set CC_FIX_ARTIFACTS_BY_STRECHING_TEXEL   1   and try

Comment: @Guru Fixed it, thanks! Think issue was that I had `[self setPosition:ccp(51.5, 0.5)];`. Want to make this an answer so I can give you some karma?

Comment: lol..already I got some karma (stupid reputation) for this answer..he he  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648443/ios-graphical-issue/12649788#12649788